# My Javascript (and Mootools) function is not returning true or false

Tags: javascript, function, mootools

I have the following function:

```
function validateField(query) {
    new Request.JSON({
        onRequest  :  function() {

        },
        onSuccess : function(json){
            return true;
        },      
        data : query + '&validate=true',
        url  : base + 'ninjquiry.php'
    }).send();              
}
```

Now onSuccess is definitely firing because I can put a console.log in there and it works, however if I do the following somewhere else:

```
console.log(validateField(query));
```

I get "undefined". Why is this ?

Thanks for any help in advance

- Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is *asynchronous*. The `onSuccess` callback is called later, after the `validateField` function has been finished. The `return true` will vanish into thin air.

You would have to either make your call synchronous - I'm sure MooTools has a setting for it - but that is highly discouraged, as it can freeze the browser.

Or, this is the better alternative, change your code so that everything relevant happens in the `onSuccess` callback.

Comment: I needed to perform some actions on an element but I suppose you're right and I can pass that element through as an argument. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @beingalex you're welcome. Passing the element through shouldn't be a problem, a variable you use in (or pass to) the `validateField` function will be automatically available in the `onSuccess` callback.